# Instantiate and apply new PhysicsMaterial2D in script (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a Unity game. In it, I want to be able to give different entities different degrees of friction without creating multiple materials in the editor. I'm currently trying to do this by defining a PhysicsMaterial2D as a member variable and instantiating it in the Start method. The material's friction is then applied based on a public member variable. I then set the actor's collider2D's sharedMaterial.

```
public class ActorUpdateScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public float friction;

    PhysicsMaterial2D actorMaterial;

    void Start () {
        actorMaterial = new PhysicsMaterial2D();
        actorMaterial.friction = friction;
        collider2D.sharedMaterial = actorMaterial;
    }
}
```

I can verify that collider2D.sharedMaterial is indeed receiving the new material, as I can print it's friction and it gives me the expected result. However, no matter what number I give it's friction, it always behaves like the default material. (0.4 friction I believe). The collision boxes he's walking on all have a material with a friction of 1.

What am I doing wrong? Does anyone have any suggestions on how to make unity pay attention to the material I've applied?

Also, before you tell me, I know I can have different materials (high friction, medium friction, low friction, etc) that I apply to different entities. But I'm planning on eventually adding super basic modding support, so the friction for a given entity will be set with a JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that you have a physics material on both your character and the floor and the combine method is to take the smaller of the two, you will always get the lower value.

To fix this you either remove the physics material from the character, set it high enough it always gets overwritten or change it depending on what you are standing on to alway get the correct behavior.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the case. When I set the floor's friction to something like 20, and the player's friction to 0.1, it doesn't treat the player like he has a friction of 0.1 Even if I set his friction to 0, the floor's high friction wins out.

Comment: The friction is a value between 0 and 1 where 0 is no friction and 1 is full friction. So if you set it to 0.1 and 20 the object will get a friction of 0.1 and will glide quite a bit, is that what you are seeing? If you set one of their frictions to 0 and the others to 1, do you get the same result as if you switch them?

Answer (score 0):

```
void Start () {
    actorMaterial = new PhysicsMaterial2D();
    collider2D.sharedMaterial = actorMaterial;

    collider2D.sharedMaterial.friction = friction;
}
```

Assign new material to collider.sharedMaterial first.

And change material value.

It works for me.